# call user function from view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 separate user functions that I need to call based on the value of another column(State). I can get it working when I place the user function after SELECT, however I need it to be placed after HAVING.

Here is the code:

```
  SELECT Fname, Lname, id, State, TotalWedThurMins, StCode
    FROM dbo.AnnualRegCredits
GROUP BY Fname, Lname, id, State, TotalWedThurMins, StCode
  HAVING (State = 'HI') 
     AND (dbo.roundnearestquarter(SUM(TotalWedThurMins)) > 0)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain the issue, with more detail?

Comment: I think you should change `HAVING (State = 'HI')` to `WHERE (State = 'HI')`.

Comment: yes, each state has to be rounded differently. 'HI' has to be rounded to nearest quarter(.25). FL has to be rounded to nearest half hour(.5). I have all the functions created and working but I am stuck trying to get them to match each state in my view. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course

HAVING is for post aggregate (eg after GROUP BY) filtering. `SUM(TotalWedThurMins)` is an aggregate. So the udf using SUM as a parmeter goes into HAVING not WHERE.

`SUM(TotalWedThurMins)` is undefined and meaningless in the WHERE clause

However, `State` is not aggregated and can be in the WHERE clause.

So it looks like this. But why GROUP BY and then SUM `TotalWedThurMins`? Perhaps you need an OVER clause to manage both... (not sure if this is valid syntax)

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, id, State, TotalWedThurMins, StCode
FROM dbo.AnnualRegCredits
WHERE (State = 'HI') 
GROUP BY Fname, Lname, id, State, TotalWedThurMins, StCode
HAVING (dbo.roundnearestquarter(SUM(TotalWedThurMins) OVER ()) > 0)
```

An alternative formulation using OVER and a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Fname, Lname, id, State, TotalWedThurMins, StCode,
           SUM(TotalWedThurMins) OVER () AS SumTotalWedThurMins
    FROM dbo.AnnualRegCredits
    WHERE State = 'HI'
)
SELECT 
     Fname, Lname, id, State, TotalWedThurMins, StCode
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    dbo.roundnearestquarter(SumTotalWedThurMins) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work but I need something different. I posted incorrect code. The code below works for two states(HI & FL). However I need a different function for MD. How do I call a different function in the same view: SELECT Fname, Lname, id, State, dbo.GetRoundDownNearestQuarter(TotalWedThurMins) AS Expr1, StCode FROM dbo.AnnualRegCredits WHERE (State = 'HI') OR (State = 'FL') GROUP BY Fname, Lname, id, State, TotalWedThurMins, StCode

Comment: Great Union All worked! Thanks! As usual the simple things never come to mind first!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the APPLY operator [here's a link](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/04/13/the-power-of-t-sqls-apply-operator/) to a good article explaining the usage and options. The APPLY operator lets you join tables to specific types of functions.